# Spring framework migration from 3.1 to 4.0, deployment on Glassfish fails with error "NoClassDefFoundError : LibraryUtils"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, glassfish

I am migrating our project from Spring 3.1 to 4.0 version. I am having the following error while trying to deploy the war to Glassfish 4 server. I am using **spring-modules-all-0.9.jar**. I have found several links related to this exception but nothing resolved my issue. Here is the error stack track from server.log :

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springmodules.validation.util.LibraryUtils
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5362)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5898)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:257)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:318)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain]]
```

Thanks for reading, let me know if you need any related information.

Comment: Spring Modules is old, really old and has been abandoned years ago. What is it that you need from that project that isn't available in spring or other projects?

Comment: i agree with @Denium springModule is very old technique for validation, you need to update this as well

Comment: Thanks for your Comments @Denium I got it. I am searching for alternative solutions to refactor my code. Please guide me, I am looking for a perfect replacement for spring-modules  with minimum refactorings.

Comment: @Denium sorry I've almost forgot to answer your question. I figured it out that we're using the BeanValidator of spring-modules-validation for validating the beans based on annotated rules in our project. I am trying to migrate this to the spring 4.0 version.

Comment: @Diablo what did you do to get around this?

Comment: @Bhavin - I have refactored my code and removed all the validations done using the old spring validator. I have implemented some of the validation annotations which are not present in the latest bean validator.